# Geometric representation of vector addition

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces

Thinking about vectors as directed line segments, we usually represent the vector addition geometrically via either the triangle law or the parallelogram law. It seems to me that these constructions use additional structure and are therefore not a mere representation of vector addition.

For the triangle law, we perform a parallel transport of one of the vector so that it starts where the other vector ends. Parallel transport is clearly additional structure not supported by mere vector space structure. Therefore, the triangle law should not be taken as a geometrical definition of vector addition.

For the parallelogram law, we draw all the vectors from a single origin, which is an improvement on the triangle law. However, the problem with this approach is the existence of the parallel lines? Vector spaces don't provide enough structure to construct parallel lines which do not pass through the origin. For that we need the affine spaces.

So, is there a convenient geometric representation of vector addition which doesn't need additional structures?

Comment: If you think of geometric vectors as equivalence classes of directed line segments, don't you already need some notion of parallelism to determine whether two directed line segments represent the same vector or not? So the “problems” start already before you come to addition. And what space do the line segments live in to begin with? An affine space?

Comment: @HansLundmark Good point! So the problem is non-existent?

Comment: I think so, yes.